# slice different arrays and return selected values

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on a problem. I do not know the right question to ask in order to solve this problem. I have gotten what seems to be the required results but the verification problem for the solution does not work. I am not sure if I am solving  it correctly. Basically I am given an array and I have to filter out elements from that array by slicing certain ingredients.

question: "We only use the elements that the instruction tells us to. So, we need to create a slice of the given array of elements (taken from the beginning) to resemble only the elements we are using. If the instruction doesn't say anything, we only take the first element."

```
 var hammerIngredients = ['iron', 'granite', 'copper'];
 var spearIngredients = ['iron', 'granite', 'copper'];
 var panIngredients = ['iron', 'granite', 'copper'];
take(hammerIngredients); // returns ['iron']
take(spearIngredients, 2); // returns ['iron', 'granite']
take(panIngredients, 3); // return ['iron', 'granite', 'copper']
```

"If the instruction says to use more than the elements listed, we use all the elements in the array. If the instruction says to use no elements, we return an empty array."

```
var plateIngredients = ['iron', 'granite', 'copper'];
take(plateIngredients, 0); // returns []
```

So I have tried to do the program and I have done the following. It appears to work, but when I try to verify it I get that it is invalid.

```
function take(ingredients, slicer) {

if (arguments.length === 1) {
    slicer = 1;
}
if (ingredients === hammerIngredients){
    return ingredients.slice(0, slicer);
}  else if(ingredients === spearIngredients) {
    return ingredients.slice(0,slicer);
}  else if (ingredients === panIngredients) {
    return ingredients.slice(0,slicer);
}  else if (ingredients === plateIngredients) {
    return ingredients.slice(0,slicer)
}  else {
    return;
}
}
```

And I have no idea why. Help please!

Answer (score 1):

you have no logic for if the slicer parameter is 0, in which case you need to return an empty array.

Put this line in there and it should work, based on the requirements you gave:

```
if (slicer === 0) {
  return [];
}
```

Comment: If slicer = 0 I should return just the first element not the empty array.

Comment: In the example you posted, a slicer of zero returns an empty array...take(plateIngredients, 0); // returns []

Comment: Yes, but the absence of a slicer will mean that you only take the first element. Which in the hammerIngredients call would only be iron.

Answer (score 0):

You code currently only works if one of those three exact arrays are used. Does the verification code create and use only those arrays?

Your code does not need to be tied to existing ingredient arrays. After setting the default slicer value you can just:

```
return ingredients.slice(0,slicer);
```

Comment: They all do the same thing, except that they slice for different amounts.

Comment: so I can use the logic on slicer to change how much I am supposed to slice, I believe I only have to do it for hammer, spear, pan, plate.

Comment: i mean its going to be "pan" + "ingredients" or "hammer" + "ingredients". I am trying to figure out if there is a better way of solving this.